# problem in setting up react app using vite js

Tags: reactjs, installation, vite

I'm trying to set up a React project using Vite, following the steps outlined in the documentation. However, I encountered an error that I couldn't resolve on my own. Here are the details:

[image: Failed to scan for dependencies from entries]

I have followed the instructions in the documentation and checked my project's configuration files, such as `vite.config.js`. However, I haven't been able to find a solution or any relevant information in the Vite repository.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue.

Comment: It's better to paste the error as text, not images.